# Is there a documentation of the first altcoins timeline?

Tags: altcoin, history

Meaning, which altcoin was created one, in a chronological order.

It's interesting, from a historical perspective, to collect such an archive.

Answer (score 1):

When posting I forgot about [this cool site](http://mapofcoins.com) that does exactly that!